# Can we infer from the support function of a convex domain $Q$ when the boundary $\partial Q$ admits nonvanishing curvature?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, plane-curves, convex-geometry, support-function

Let $Q$ be a compact, convex domain in the plane, with smooth boundary $\partial Q$. We further assume that the origin is contained in $Q$. For a concrete example, let's take an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\le1$.

The support function of $Q$ is given by $\displaystyle h(\theta)=\sup_{\mathbf{q}\in Q}\;\mathbf{q}\cdot \langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$.

We can recover a convex domain from its support function by tracking the caustics of the supporting lines $L_\theta=\{h(\theta)\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle+t\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (Edit: More precisely, this gives the boundary of $Q$, not $Q$ itself.). So $h$ should be able to characterize $Q$. My questions are:

1. is there some kind of characterization of $h$ such that the domain $Q$ is convex (strictly convex, respectively)?
2. Assume $Q$ is already strictly convex. Is there any characterization of $h$ such that the boundary $\partial Q$ admits nonvanishing curvature?

Thank you! :)

---

Edit: as Harald's comment below, the resulting domain $Q=Q(h)$ is *always* convex, since it is the intersection of a family of convex domains--half planes.  Thank you Harald!

Let's start with arbitrary $2\pi$-periodic, positive function $h$, and obtain a convex domain $Q=Q(h)$. Then we can reconsider the support function $g=g(Q)=g(Q(h))$ of $Q$, which might be different from $h$. This happens if $Q$ does not touch the boundary of some half plane.

So we may restrict our attention to the class of **faithful** support functions, those satisfy the condition $g(Q(h))=h$.

Comment: Don't you recover the domain by taking the complement of the unions of the supporting lines?

Comment: But actually, I think a better way to recover $Q$ is as the intersection of containing half spaces $H_\theta=\{\,\mathbf{q}:\mathbf{q}\cdot(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\le h(\theta)\,\}$. Now this produces a convex set for any $h$, which could be useful.

Comment: Yes you are right. The envelop of moving lines above will trace out the boundary of $Q$. The table is given by the intersection of the left-half planes separated by the lines.

Comment: I think the first question is asking when a given $h$ is the support function of some convex domain $Q$. As I recall, if the origin is inside $Q$ it has to be Lipschitz continuous, positive, $2\pi$-periodic and $h+h''>0$, where the last condition is interpreted in the distributional sense in general ($h+h''$ can be a measure).

Comment: @Conifold where can I find a reference for that result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there some kind of characterization of $h$ such that the domain $Q$ is convex

No, because the support function of $Q$ is equal to the support function of the convex hull of $Q$.

> is there some kind of characterization of $h$ such that the domain $Q$ is **strictly** convex

Yes: if and only if $h$ is differentiable. In other words, if and only if the [polar set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_set) of $Q$ has smooth boundary. It's worth noticing that the polar of polar set is the original set.

A corner in a convex set creates a line segment in the boundary of its polar, because the value of support function comes from the same point (the corner) for some interval of   $\theta$. Conversely, suppose the boundary of a convex set contains a vertical segment to the right of origin. Then $h$ is not differentiable at $\theta=0$, because a small change of $\theta$ *in either direction* increases $h$ at a linear rate. (So, the graph of $h$ has a nonsmooth minimum like $|\theta|$.)

The general form of the above is known as *duality of smoothness and rotundity*, and it holds in all finite dimensional spaces.

> Is there any characterization of $h$ such that the boundary $\partial  Q$ admits nonvanishing curvature?

Yes: if and only if $h\in C^2$.  I recommend [Convex Bodies: The Brunn-Minkowski Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=2QhT8UCKx2kC) by Rolf Schneider, specifically section 2.5 *Higher regularity and curvature*.  For the two-dimensional case, see also page 2 of [Lectures on Mean Curvature Flows](http://books.google.com/books?id=VnG5TzcyN4wC) by Xi-Ping Zhu.

*Sketch*. Introduce the Gauss map $\nu:\partial Q\to S^1$ which gives exterior unit normal vector at every boundary point. This map is defined when $Q$ has $C^1$ boundary. If  $\partial Q$ is also strictly convex, then $\nu$ is injective. And if $\partial Q$ has nonvanishing curvature, then $\nu$ is a diffeomorphism -- indeed, this is *if and only if*, because the derivative of $\nu$ *is* the curvature of $\partial Q$.

It is convenient to define $h_Q$ as a function on $\mathbb R^2$, via $h_Q(x)=\sup_{q\in Q} x\cdot q$. Then one can check  that $ h_Q(x)= x\cdot \nu^{-1}(x/|x|) $ and 
$ \nabla h_Q(x)=  \nu^{-1}(x/|x|)$.

Thus, the equivalence is: nonvanishing curvature $\iff$ $\nu $ is a diffeomorphism $\iff$ $h_Q\in   C^2(\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\})$.

Comment: Thank you and I will check your updates later :)

Comment: @Pengfei Updated. What I wrote is a sketch: explaining every step is tedious, especially when this already done in a book (see the links to Google books above).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful!